# Why doesn't justify-content work in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

Im trying to center to div's , inside a container div with flex. flex-wrap works, align-items works, justify-content does not want to work. :(

```
      <div className="container">
        
        <div className="card-container">

          <h1>Computer</h1>
          <Card cardValue={sendCardToComputer} />
          <p>Points: {computerPoint}</p>
          <p>Round Won: {props.roundLost}</p>
          <br />

        </div>

        <hr />
      
       <div className="card-container">
          <h1>{props.player}</h1>
          <Card cardValue={sendCardToPlayer} />
          <p>Points: {playerPoint}</p>
          <p>Rounds Won: {props.roundWin}</p>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  /* padding: 30px; */
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.card-container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: salmon;
  border: 2px solid black;

}
.card{
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1.5px solid blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Justify-content just does not want to work.. help? im trying to decide how to use justify-content but no option works.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `<hr>`, it will work. The `hr` is also `display: flex`, and is pushing the boxes to each side of the screen. That is an extra flex element that is throwing things out:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  /* padding: 30px; */
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.card-container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: salmon;
  border: 2px solid black;

}
.card{
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1.5px solid blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-container">
    <h1>Computer</h1>
    <Card cardValue={sendCardToComputer} />
    <p>Points: {computerPoint}</p>
    <p>Round Won: {props.roundLost}</p>
    <br />
  </div>

 <div class="card-container">
    <h1>{props.player}</h1>
    <Card cardValue={sendCardToPlayer} />
    <p>Points: {playerPoint}</p>
    <p>Rounds Won: {props.roundWin}</p>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```